# Discount amount not showing on checkout

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, discount

I have created rule 50% discount. When buying product it does apply discount on the price but it does not showing that discount amount on checkout.
I tried to do my research and I found that I need this in my code:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component"     xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

And I do have this in my code. Please, help me print out the discount amount from the catalog price rule as I am obligated to show the discount in my order and invoice email and pdf. Right now the discount amount is showing 0%, but it is set to be 50%.

Please help.